# CUDA cudaMalloc

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I've started writing a new CUDA application. However I hit a funny detour along the way.
Calling the first cudaMalloc on a variable x, fails the first time. However when I call it the second time it returns cudaSuccess. Recently upgraded to CUDA 4.0 SDK, it's a really weird bug.

I even did some testing and it seems the first call of cudaMalloc fails.

Comment: On a side note it doesn't matter how much memory I'm allocating which was my first guess relating to memory alignment issues.

Comment: cudaGetLastError may return errors from previous async calls if that's what you mean by failure.

Comment: Could you include a small example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very first call to any of the cuda library functions launches an initialisation subroutine. It can happen that somehow the initialisation fails and not the cudaMalloc itself. (CUDA Programming Guide, section 3.2.1)

Somehow, later, however it seems it works, despite the initial failure. I don't know your setting and your code so I can't really help you further. Check the Programming Guide!

Answer (score 3):

I <s>would strongly recommend</s> using the `CUDA_SAFE_CALL` macro if you aren't -- to force the thread synchronisation, at least while you're debugging the code:

```
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**) &(myVar), mem_size_N ));
```

**Update:** As per @talonmies, you don't need the cutil library.  So let's rewrite the solution:

```
/*  Allocate Data  */
cudaMalloc((void**) &(myVar), mem_size_N );

/*  Force Thread Synchronization  */
cudaError err = cudaThreadSynchronize();

/*  Check for and display Error  */
if ( cudaSuccess != err )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",
             __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );
}
```

And as noted in the other answer -- you may want to include the synch & check before you allocation memory just to make sure the API initialized correctly.

Comment: Don't, however, build any dependence on cutils from the SDK into your code. Just copy the macro and use it (BSD license so no problem in doing so). For a whole host of reasons, using cutils is a bad idea.

Comment: @talonmies, I've been using cutils on Ubuntu, Redhat, and Windows with no issues.  Have you filed bug reports or questions on [so] for the problems you come across?

Comment: It isn't that there are problems with cutils. It is that the headers and library functions  exists only to support the SDK examples. There is no documentation, and no guarantees about correctness or functionality, or that features will be preserved between releases. NVIDIA employees specifically advise not to use cutil in production code [for example](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=106381&view=findpost&p=586994) and [another](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=92389&view=findpost&p=519951)

Comment: Oh. (implied explicitives)  Wish that was more prominently stated.  Thanks @talonmies.