# Allocating array of strings in cuda

Tags: cuda, gpu

Let us assume that we have the following strings that we need to store in a CUDA array.

"hi there"

"this is"

"who is"

How do we declare a array on the GPU to do this. I tried using C++ `strings` but it does not work.

Comment: Do you really mean "CUDA array" (as in spatially ordered data for use with textures and surfaces) or do you mean "array usable for general global memory access inside a kernel"?

Comment: @talonmies: I just need to create an array of strings and access it in global memory. Something like char** array in C. How can we do this for the GPU. Moreover, as there are no strcmp function in CUDA, what is the workaround for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this is to use structure that is similar to common compressed sparse matrix formats. Store the character data packed into a single piece of linear memory, then use a separate integer array to store the starting indices, and perhaps a third array to store the string lengths. The storage overhead of the latter might be more efficient that storing a string termination byte for every entry in the data and trying to parse for the terminator inside the GPU code.

So you might have something like this:

```
struct gpuStringArray {
    unsigned int * pos; 
    unsigned int * length;  // could be a smaller type if strings are short
    char4 * data; // 32 bit data type will improve memory throughput, could be 8 bit
}
```

Note I used a `char4` type for the string data; the vector type will give better memory throughput, but it will mean strings need to be aligned/suitably padded to 4 byte boundaries. That may or may not be a problem depending on what a typical real string looks like in your application. Also, the type of the (optional) length parameter should probably be chosen to reflect the maximum admissible string length. If you have a lot of very short strings, it might be worth using an 8 or 16 bit unsigned type for the lengths to save memory.

---

A *really* simplistic code to compare strings stored this way in the style of `strcmp` might look something like this:

```
__device__ __host__
int cmp4(const char4 & c1, const char4 & c2)
{
    int result;

    result = c1.x - c2.x; if (result !=0) return result; 
    result = c1.y - c2.y; if (result !=0) return result; 
    result = c1.z - c2.z; if (result !=0) return result; 
    result = c1.w - c2.w; if (result !=0) return result; 

    return 0;
}

__device__ __host__
int strncmp4(const char4 * s1, const char4 * s2, const unsigned int nwords)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<nwords; i++) {
        int result = cmp4(s1[i], s2[i]);
        if (result != 0) return result;
    }

    return 0;
}

__global__
void tkernel(const struct gpuStringArray a, const gpuStringArray b, int * result)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    char4 * s1 = a.data + a.pos[idx];
    char4 * s2 = b.data + b.pos[idx];
    unsigned int slen = min(a.length[idx], b.length[idx]);

    result[idx] = strncmp4(s1, s2, slen);
}
```

[disclaimer: never compiled, never tested, no warranty real or implied, use at your own risk]

There are some corner cases and assumptions in this which might catch you out depending on exactly what the real strings in your code look like, but I will leave those as an exercise to the reader to resolve. You should be able to adapt and expand this into whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks useful. However, how do I compare two strings on the GPU?

Comment: I gave you one up for this much. will be obliged if you could answer the question in my comment

Comment: @Programmer: "this much" completely answers the question you asked. I didn't see any reference to string comparison in the original question. But I have made a small edit that might give you a start on whatever it is you are actually trying to acheive.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use C-style character strings `char *str`. Searching for "CUDA string" on google would have given you this CUDA "Hello World" example as first hit: http://computer-graphics.se/hello-world-for-cuda.html
There you can see how to use `char*`-strings in CUDA. Be aware that standard C-functions like `strcpy` or `strcmp` are not available in CUDA!

If you want an array of strings, you just have to use `char**` (as in C/C++). As for `strcmp` and similar functions, it highly depends on what you want to do. CUDA is not really well suited for string operations, maybe it would help if you would provide a little more detail about what you want to do.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - he wants to know how to store and manage an **array** of strings in the GPU, not a single string.

Comment: I thought the main problem were the strings themselves (since Programmer tried to use C++ stings in CUDA!). From there, it should quite simple to create an array of strings. I noticed that this question is very similar to those two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566910/cuda-char-variable-assignment and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561005/output-of-cuda-program-is-not-what-was-expected .